# Using the entity modal with mvc -mvvm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi there I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I want to create an mvc applicaton I have worked my way through the music store example and still am not 100% sure the correct way to do things.

Lets say I want to create an application that stores cooking receipes.
I have a 3 tables

RecipeTable
RecipeID
RecipeName

RecipeIngredients
RecipeIngredientID
RecipeID
IngredientID
Measurement

IngredientTable
IngredientID
IngredientName

All have PK & FK mappings very basic, I create a new mvc application and use the entity framework to create a new entity e.g. RecipeDB

My next step is I create a new model for each of the tables and give the properties my desired displaynames and specify required fields extra.

Do I then create a viewmodel e.g. RecipesViewModel that looks something like

```
public class RecipesViewModel
{
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeIngredients> { get; set; }

}
```

I now create the controller (Ithink) but I am not really sure how to bind that to database entity.

I know you can call the database by doing something like RecipeEntities db = new recipeEntites(); however binding the results to the vm I am little confussed on how to do that.

Am I heading in the right direction so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). It's a great tool allowing you to convert from one type to another and in your case from the model to the view model.

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    RecipeDB model = _repository.GetRecipies();
    RecipesViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<RecipeDB, RecipesViewModel>(model);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

or you could even define a custom action attribute (like the [one I used in my sample MVC project](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc/blob/master/src/SampleMvc.Web/Mvc/AutoMapAttribute.cs)) allowing you to simply write:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(RecipeDB), typeof(RecipesViewModel))]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    RecipeDB model = _repository.GetRecipies();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi again Darin :) what is _repository is that just a private RecipeDB _repository = new RecipeDB()?

Comment: @Diver Dan, it is an interface which is passed to the constructor of the controller. This interface contains the operations on your model.